# Emacs: How to undo multiple things at a time?

Tags: emacs

> Emacs: How to undo multiple things at a time?

I find myself pressing `C-x u` multiple times to undo, e.g., a line or some other edits...

How do I undo things faster, like holding `CTRL+z` down in other editors?

Comment: You can also use `C-_` or `C-/` to undo your change. You can use these as the same way as `Ctrl+z` in other editors.

Comment: Are they different from C-x u in terms of functionality?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Then what are the benefits of using them compared to C-x u ? Thanks btw.

Comment: @Shuzheng `undo` is bound to all of those keys, they all run the exact same command.  Use whichever key you find most comfortable.  Personally, I use the excellent `undo-tree` and bind `undo-tree-undo` to `C-z` and `undo-tree-redo` to `C-S-z`.